# Is there a code to turn on Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library?

Tags: vba

I have used FileSystem Object in my code and it relies on the user having turned on his Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library. Is there a code by which I can turn on this library on the user's Excel application?

Comment: Look up late binding.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way: 
Check if `Scripting` is not activated in `references` of the `VBAproject` then add it otherwise do nothing

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Ref As Object, CheckRefEnabled%
    CheckRefEnabled = 0
    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each Ref In .VBProject.References
            If Ref.Name = "Scripting" Then
                CheckRefEnabled = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Ref
        If CheckRefEnabled = 0 Then
            .VBProject.References.AddFromGUID "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}", 1, 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vasily's answer works, but a user will still have to enable the option `Trust Access to the VBA Project object model` in excel or any other microsoft office program.

`File` -> `Options` -> `Trust Center` -> `Trust Center Setttings` -> `Macro Settings` -> `Trust Access to the VBA Project object model`

Comment: Surely easier to use late binding though.  No need to muck around with the VBE and trusting access to the VBA model then.